# How can I change a button's function based on a tableview selection?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uibutton

I have a populated tableview as well as a button that plays a sound.I would like the button to play different sounds depending on what is selected in the table view.

**How can I retrieve what row is selected in the table view when the button is pressed? Is there a better way to do this?**

Thanks, and here's the code:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL *buttonURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"applause_y" ofType:@"wav"]];

    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)buttonURL, 
                                     &SoundID);

    NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Sleepy", @"Sneezy",
                      @"Bashful", @"Happy", @"Doc", @"Grumpy", @"Dopey", @"Thorin", @"Dorin", @"Nori", @"Ori", @"Balin", @"Dwalin", @"Fili", @"Kili", @"Oin", @"Gloin", @"Bifur", @"Bofur", @"Bombur", nil];
    self.listData = array;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    NSString *rowValue = [listData objectAtIndex:row];
    NSString *message = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"You selected %@", rowValue];

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Row Selected!"
                                                    message:message
                                                   delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Yes I Did"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES]; 
}

//Button that plays sound
- (IBAction)Button:(id)sender
{
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SoundID);
}
```

Comment: Update your `Button` method (BTW - method names should begin with lowercase letters) to base the sound id on the currently selected row.

Comment: Done. Thanks for the tip rmaddy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better way to do this would be to change your data source to associate each item to a sound.

So instead of the array it would be an array of pair values

```
self.listData = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                    @{@"mood":@"Sleepy", @"sound":@"applause_y"},
                    @{@"mood":@"Sneezy", @"sound":@"sound_a"},
                    @{@"mood":@"Bashful", @"sound":@"sound_b"},
                    @{@"mood":@"Happy", @"sound":@"sound_c"},
                    //and so forth
                    ];
```

your count would not change:

```
[self.listData count];
```

But the way you retrieve the data would be a little different:

```
[[self.listData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"mood"];
```

In your IBAction you don't have access to indexPath so in order to get the sound you have to get that from the tableView:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
[[self.listData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"sound"];
```

but watch out for the last line of code in didSelectedRow, you might need to comment that out.

```
//[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
```

or move it to the method where you play the sound, after playing it of course.

Comment: For this to work,would I have to declare a tableView property in my .h file as well?

Comment: No, Unless you did not use a UITableViewController where you can just do self.tableView

Comment: Worked perfectly Thank you meda and Rob.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your IBAction you should just be able to call `[myTableView indexPathForSelectedRow]` and use that to decide what sound to play.

In this case I am guessing your table has 1 section with a bunch of rows, so you can take `[listData objectAtIndex:[[myTableView indexPathForSelectedRow] row]]` to get one of your Dwarf names, for example.

Comment: obviously myTableView is not to be taken literally. You'll have to use some property you've got already to get at the tableview in this View Controller's view.